# Won't show loading until ajax finish

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am calling a function on click on a checkbox. The problem is that I am using an ajax call here and the checkbox is not checked until the ajax finish.
As the call is taking some data from web service it takes time, so until it returns data everything is frozen.

That's why I want to add loading, but also it is not showing until there is a response from ajax.

This is only the case with Chrome, with Mozilla it works fine.

Here  is the code:

```
$.ajax({
    url:  shopurl,
    type: 'get',
    data: 'cl=alist&filterMan=' + chkArrayM,
    dataType: 'html',
    async: false,
    beforeSend: function(){
      var img_loading = document.getElementById("loadingImage");
   document.getElementById("loadingImage").className="loading_active";
   },
   success: function(data){
      $('#listitems').hide().html(data).fadeIn('slow');
    }
```

Comment: make `async: true`

Comment: If you use jquery, you can just call $('#id') instead of document.getElementById. There's also a jquery function to toggle classes, which would be a better approach imo.

Comment: @PatricL thanks very much. This works!